# protoc --version is not showing anything

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I installed [protocol-buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) in C++ in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS PC by following instructions provided at official GitHub page [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md).

There was no error reported during installation. However, I would like to verify the installation hence I run `protoc --version` but it returned following error message:

```
The program 'protoc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler
```

I am wondering why it is behaving like this? Am I missing something obvious?

I want to generate CPP and header file for my protocol buffers message file as well.

Comment: Where have you installed `protoc`, and is it in your PATH? What you can do is to configure and build the protoc again using `./configure --prefix=/usr`, which should be in PATH.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard : it worked after using `./configure --prefix=/usr`. However I am wondering that this could have done automatically. Isn't it? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: You could have installed it in any location and simply `export PATH=$PATH:path/to/your/protoc/folder` or edit some of the .rc files, such as .bashrc or .zshrc with PATH added to it.